# Не могу залить проект на сервер. Выдает ошибки

Tags: html5, angular

Пытался залить на сервер проекты Angular, уже собранные(с HTML, с папкой dist) выдает те же ошибки, что и на github pages. Когда заливаю на github pages один проект, то работает, а если два, то уже нет.

[image: Ошибки при запросе]

Comment: Замените все абсолютные (с `/` в начале) ссылки на относительные или добавьте правильный префикс к абсолютным?

Comment: спасибо большое. мысль очень правильная, с "css" решилось, а к js файлам не могу правильный путь прописать